# Bootstrap: prevent navigation bar from collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to build a non-responsive website. I have a navigation bar as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Something</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="link">Item 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="link">Item 2</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Something Else</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="link">Item 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="link">Item 4</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When the browser width shrinks, the navigation bar collapses to display menu items vertically. I do not want the navigation bar to have any change no matter how the browser width changes. I want it to be static. How can I do this? I understand this is going to be CSS tricks, but dont know how to start.

**Update**

I am abandoning the plan to adapt Bootstrap's navbars for a non-responsive website. Here is from Bootstrap itself http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

*As a heads up, the navbar component is rather tricky here in that the styles for displaying it are rather specific and detailed. Overrides to ensure desktop styles display are not as performant or sleek as one would like. Just be aware there may be potential gotchas as you build on top of this example when using the navbar.*

There are a lot of simple CSS menus out there.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the relevant area of the Bootstrap docs (Presuming that you're using Bootstrap 3.0) [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

Comment: Karl, thanks for chiming in! The link you provided says "If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior", and it does not provide any details. This is exactly what I am asking. Regards.

Comment: @curious1, you're right, on second read the docs are very vague. Most of the Bootstrap responsive stuff is triggered by way of media queries and data toggles unless called via JS explicitly. I imagine if you were to modify the main Bootstrap CSS and pruned it all out, as well as removing all data toggles and relevant collapse classes, you could remove the behaviour as they say, but I do agree that depending on your requirements it may be less work to simply implement something else or write your own. Best of luck either way!

Comment: Karl, thanks for your follow-up. Nice communication with you!

Comment: @curious1: Always happy to help wherever I can, nice to communicate with you too :)

Comment: There should be a way to disable navbar collapse without having to throw the baby out with the water.